# Transpilar no desenvolvimento ou só no build

Tags: typescript, build, scss, bundle

Preciso transpilar um projeto pois usa scss, typescript e Es6

O correto é fazer o bundle somente pra o build ou posso/devo rodar uma task toda vez que eu alterar o código?

Gostaria de saber como é no mercado. Se é comum gerar o bundle durante o desenvolvimento, para ver a aplicação funcionando ou é adotada outra prática.

Comment: Você **precisa** gerar um bundle para ter o projeto funcionando no local?

Comment: Não necessariamente. Eu posso configurar um server com babel. Mesmo assim eu teria que compilar o scss. Mas queria saber qual a prática comum nas empresas e equipes de desenvolvimento. Particularmente eu acho que gerar o bundle ajudaria a detectar falhas na transpilação, mas atrapalharia debugar